# Cron tab pattern to run a script once in a year/ once in lifetime

Tags: python, linux, automation, cron

I am looking for crontab pattern that should run my python script once in a year. Below is the date and time I am looking to trigger my script through crontab.

Date: Aug-16-2017, Time: 5:00PM (should trigger the script only once this year at this specified time)

Can someone please help me with this?

Note: Im actually looking for something that should trigger my script in the background for once and leave it running (coz my script has infinite loop so once triggered and keep the process alive in the background should do good). For this I used "at" command (from googling I see "at" jobs are triggered once at a specific time and will kept alive until/unless the server/system reboots which is fine with me). But looks like "at" job didnt work as expected. I started "at" job at 12:20 PM PST which should keep my script running and my script is expected to send an output and 1:15 PM PST. Just to test this, I closed SSH session at 1:00 PM. Before closing I see output "atq" showing jobs triggered by at. But later when I re-sshed into the server again, I dont see any jobs running under "at".

Can some one please help me one of these problems? Ultimately I m looking for a solution to keep the process alive for ever in the background.

Comment: If you want to keep a process alive forever, you should be using a process supervision system -- systemd (on most new Linux distros), launchd (on MacOS), Upstart (where supported), [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), etc. cron is the wrong tool for the job; atd, likewise.

Comment: ...a real process supervision system will be immediately notified when your program exits (so it doesn't need to occasionally poll), will know *how* it exits, and will provide the user with the means to indicate whether they want the process to be kept up, kept down, run once and allowed to exit if it chooses, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you give an example/syntax/usage of this supervision? And would there be any logs to check whether the process is running? Does this keep the process alive even when ssh out of the session? Thanks!

Comment: systemd timers? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers

Comment: Each of these tools has its own usage; which one is appropriate depends on your target operating system. Do you know which init system your target OS ships with?

Comment: @GrishaS, a timer is appropriate to run a job on a schedule, but the OP really wants to kick off their process whenever it exits, so they just want a regular service, not a timer.

Comment: @chaitanya, see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet for some hints on what command-line usage looks like, and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_customize_a_unit_file.2F_add_a_custom_unit_file.3F for a high-level guide on adding your own service file, *if* your Linux distro is based on systemd.

Comment: Sure..Let me take a look at it. Thanks Charles and @Grisha S

Comment: Mean while a question. is "nohup" any use here? How long does it keep the process alive? I mean does it kill at the time of ssh(ing) out? or at the time of server reboot? or is there any instance where it lose tracking of running process/kills it when the server is online?

Answer (score 1):

Cron isn't suited for this, because it runs programs based on a certain interval.

A clean solution would be to use Supervisor: http://supervisord.org/

Install supervisor through your package manager, make your script executable, and add this to `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/$YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.conf`, then restart supervisor.

```
[program:$YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME]
command=$PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

You can set the locations for the log and error output files in the config file too: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks much for detailed info @Eric...Let me take a look at this

Answer (score -1):

lets start to create the system you need :

first of all you need to create a runner script for your python code :

`/usr/local/bin/my_runner` :

```
#!/bin/bash
python /path/to/my/script
```

`$sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/my_runner`

then you need to create `/usr/local/bin/startup_runner`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "@reboot    /usr/local/bin/my_runner" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
crontab -u root -l | grep -v '/usr/local/bin/startup_runner'  | crontab -u root -
```

`$sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup_runner`

at the end of this , you must go for the first caller at Aug-16-2017, Time: 5:00PM

`$sudo crontab -e`

add the following to the end of crontab file

```
0 17 16 8 *    /usr/local/bin/startup_runner
```

this will work fine for you , any questions about the scripts ?

Comment: Appreciate your response. Does "startup_runner" script reboot my server? and then while bringing up does it set the crontab to trigger the script at Aug-16-2017, Time: 5:00PM?

Comment: If not, can you explain what startup_runner script does here? and does crontab pattern trigger at 5:00 PM? Im just concerned about the time.

Comment: startup_runner is the script that tells the crontab , at every reboot my_runner must run.

Comment: in crontab @reboot means , run the script at system startup

Comment: at Aug-16-2017, Time: 5:00PM script startup_runner executes, so the system knows that after Aug-16-2017, Time: 5:00PM, at every restart, the code in my_runner must be executed, i think this is exactly what you need

Comment: ok what if there is no reboot? Assume system is up and running now and made this environment and add cron entry as "0 17 16 8 *    /usr/local/bin/startup_runner" , how does this trigger "my_runner" script at 5:00 PM today? Sorry for being dumb. Please explain

Comment: that part just manages reboots, that code only makes you sure that event the system reboots, at start up your code will run,

Comment: not only this code works with system reboots, but also it will work with no reboots

Comment: My system is up and running now and I know your solution would make my life easy when I reboot (but not thinking of a reboot any time sooner). But in addition to this I m looking for something that should trigger my py script at 5 PM today and keep that process alive forever (i know there are few exception when the cronjob fails). But Im expecting that a solution should keep the cronjob alive even if i close the terminal/ ssh out of the terminal

Comment: Ok Let me try setting this up and get back to you

Comment: for changing it to run today at 5, you must change 16 and 8 with todays date, and actually you can run it manually :D

Comment: Can you reconfirm this line in startup_runner - "crontab -u root -l | grep -v '/usr/local/bin/startup_runner'  | crontab -u root -" ....is there "l" at the very end? or is it correct the way you posted?

Comment: it' correct. as it is